# Golang SQL Error: "pq: relation "userdata" does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pq

I am making a simple CRUD app with Golang using a postgres database hosted on my computer. I am using the sql driver https://github.com/lib/pq.
I am able to successfully store users in the database from a POST request with the following code

```
func createUser(name string, email string, password string) {
  psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, port, user, password, dbname)
  db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
  _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO USERDATA (name,email,password) VALUES($1,$2,$3);", name, email, password)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
  db.Close()
}
```

However When I try to use very similar code to look up a user with data from a GET request it give the error "pq: relation "userdata" does not exist". I do not understand how it cannot find the sql table userdata when it is able to create a user in that table.
The following code is the code that generates the error.

```
func lookUpEmail(email string) User {
  psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
"password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, port, user, password, dbname)
  db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

  if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR 0")
    panic(err)
    }
  fmt.Println(os.Stdout,"Succesfully connected")

  row := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE email = $1", email)
  if row.Err() != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR 1")
    panic(row.Err())
  }
  user := new(User)
  err = row.Scan(&user.name,&user.email,&user.password)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR 2")
    panic(err)
  }
  return *user
}
```

This code returns error : "pq: relation "userdata" does not exist"

If I type in the query "SELECT * FROM USERDATA WHERE email = (insert email)" into my sql console it works fine.

Comment: Are both functions connecting to the same database?  Because a database is safe for concurrent use, it's typical to open the database once at application startup instead of on each use.

Comment: can you share your db migration file?

Comment: Yes they are connecting to the same database.

Answer (score 0):

check carefully your `dbname=%s` parameter and check does your table actually created in `%s` namespace.
In postgres you need to for example `\c test` where 'test' is namespace(db) name, if not you can try to create db in the next way by using docker-compose file

```html
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - /_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: test

volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local
```

```
Set volumes related to you directory
```